# MySQL / PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, data-migration

I've recently taken over a WordPress site from another 'dev' company. The site is highly unstable and not delivering what the client needs. So, I'm currently trying to export the site wholesale to one of our company server.

Numerous backup plugins have failed for various reasons, so I'm now trying to get an export of the MySQL database via phpmyadmin to import into our MySQL server. I've taken a full export from the old server and tried importing it into the new server via phpmyadmin . However, this fails after a period of time, with no real indicator of why.

Next, I exported every table individually and tried to import them to the new server. The first 2/3 or so appear to work but then the latter 1/3 all fail to import with the output/error message saying that the table has multiple primary keys declared.

I really need to export the database structure and data from the old server and transfer it to the new one. So, I'm really perplexed as to what my next move could be. If these tables have multiple primary keys and this prevents an import, how were they created in the first place??

What can I do to remedy the situation and get the data migrated?

Comment: PHP my admin would give a reason, else possibly a timeout? There may also be limits on the filesize, how big is the SQL file?

Comment: The compressed export for the whole database is apparently 2,192KB.

Comment: Have you tried with the good old and simple `mysql -u UNAME -p db_name < data.sql`, since phpMyAdmin depends on all the `php.ini` settings like `max_execution_time`, `post_max_size`, etc?

Comment: To be honest MySQL isn't my forte so that's new to me. Could you expand on what this does and what I should expect from it?

Comment: It simply imports the data from the dump file `data,sql` into your MySQL database `db_name`. Just google `mysql import dump` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this was related to some limiting factor with PHP / phpMyAdmin. I was able to import the generated SQL scripts via the SQL tool in Virtualmin / Webmin without any apparent issue.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a problem of the dump you get. If it was too big, your phpmyadmin would just break down after a while. If you have ssh access to your server you could easily import your dump by shell after uploading your dump file to your server. If this is not possible you could maybe work with a big dump script http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/ which automatically imports the dump partially, so there is no server timeout anymore.

Comment: Good call on SSH. Best way of doing these sort of things

Comment: But SSH will not magically load his dump into MYSQL, so not really an answer to the question.

Comment: Don't know which host runs the server so there is no ssh dump command that I could recommend. Might defer...

Comment: It appears that the issue was actually at the import end of the process. Using a different tool to import the SQL worked without any issues being presented.